# Compare two tables and display missing data - Power BI

Tags: excel, powerbi

I have hundreds of lines with different courses that my employees took during the year. And I also have another table with the mandatory courses they have to take... I want to find a way to compare those two tables and see what courses are missing. I would also appreciate if someone help me giving me ideas to perform a "completion bar" (example: employee 1: 78% courses taken)

To illustrate a little bit the data that I have:

Table 1(TRAINING 2021)

Bruno    | Course A
Bruno    | Course B

Table 2(MANDATORY TRAINING 2021)

Course A
Course B
Course C

Desired output (missing courses):

Bruno    | Course C

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

See the comments in the code, and explore the Applied Steps window, to understand the algorithm

**Training2021**
[image]

**MandatoryTraining2021**
[image]

**M Code**

```
let
    Training2021= Table.FromRecords(
        {[Name="Bruno", Course="Course A"],
        [Name="Bruno", Course="Course B"],
        [Name="George",Course="Course A"],
        [Name="George",Course="Course C"],
        [Name="Sandra",Course="Course C"]},
        type table [Name=Text.Type, Course=Text.Type]),
    MandatoryTraining2021= Table.FromRecords(
        {[Course="Course A"],
        [Course="Course B"],
        [Course="Course C"]},
        type table[Course=Text.Type]),

//group training table by Name
    group = Table.Group(Training2021,"Name",
                {"Courses", each [Course]}
            ),

//Missing courses using List.RemoveMatchingItems
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(group, "Missed", each 
            Text.Combine(
                List.RemoveMatchingItems(
                    MandatoryTraining2021[Course],[Courses]),"; "), type text),

//Percent Completed
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "% Taken", each 
        List.Count([Courses])/Table.RowCount(MandatoryTraining2021),Percentage.Type),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Courses"})


in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

**Results**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check this solution
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Finding-differences-between-tables/m-p/328736#M146789

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If your `Table 1` is like this

```
| name   | course  |
|--------|---------|
| Bruno  | CourseA |
| Bruno  | CourseB |
| George | CourseA |
| George | CourseB |
| George | CourseC |
| Sam    | CourseB |
```

and `Table 2` is like this

```
| mandatoryCourse |
|-----------------|
| CourseA         |
| CourseB         |
| CourseC         |
```

You need following two measures to achieve what you desire

```
_missingCourses =
VAR _0 =
    CROSSJOIN ( 'Table 1', 'Table 2' )
VAR _1 =
    EXCEPT (
        SUMMARIZE ( _0, 'Table 1'[name], 'Table 2'[mandatoryCourse] ),
        SUMMARIZE ( _0, 'Table 1'[name], 'Table 1'[course] )
    )
RETURN
    CONCATENATEX ( _1, [mandatoryCourse], ",", [mandatoryCourse], ASC )



% Completion =
VAR _0 =
    CROSSJOIN ( 'Table 1', 'Table 2' )
VAR _1 =
    INTERSECT (
        SUMMARIZE ( _0, 'Table 1'[name], 'Table 2'[mandatoryCourse] ),
        SUMMARIZE ( _0, 'Table 1'[name], 'Table 1'[course] )
    )
VAR _3 =
    COUNT ( 'Table 2'[mandatoryCourse] )
VAR _4 =
    COUNTX ( _1, [mandatoryCourse] )
VAR _5 =
    DIVIDE ( _4, _3 )
RETURN
    _5
```

[image: Solution]