# Compare two different tables and list missing values

Tags: excel

I have a similar table on Excel like this:

| ID | Courses |
| --- | --- |
| John | CourseA |
| Bruno | CourseB |
| John | CourseC |
| John | CourseD |

I have another table with mandatory courses:

| Mandatory courses |
| --- |
| CourseA |
| CourseB |
| CourseB |
| CourseD |

Desired output:

| ID | Missing Courses |
| --- | --- |
| John | CourseB |
| Bruno | CourseA,CourseC,CourseD |

Can you please help me to find a formula to automate this process? Thanks a lot.

Comment: We can help. Please edit your question to show what you have tried and where you ran into problems. What was wrong with the answers you received to this very similar question yesterday [Compare two tables and display missing data - Power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69547971/compare-two-tables-and-display-missing-data-power-bi). It would be courteous to respond there with clarification before reposting the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a combination of 2 formula's.

Consider your 1st table is in range `A1:B5` & the Mandatory column is in range `E1:E5` (first row are headers)

1. 1st formula to create a list of unique ID's: `=UNIQUE(A2:A5)` - where `A2:A5` is your first table.

   - Consider that the spill range output of this is in range `A10:A11`
2. 2nd column beside the Unique ID column:
   `=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, FILTER($E$2:$E$5, ISERROR(VLOOKUP($E$2:$E$5, FILTER( FILTER( $A$2:$B$5, $A$2:$A$5=A10), {0,1}), 1, FALSE)), ""))`

   - You need to drag this column against all rows in Unique ID's

---

Formula split into multiple lines for better readability

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, 
     FILTER($E$2:$E$5, 
         ISERROR(VLOOKUP($E$2:$E$5, FILTER(
                   FILTER($A$2:$B$5, $A$2:$A$5=A10),
                                     {0,1}),
                 1,FALSE)
               ),
           "")
         )
```

Sample Screenshot of working example:
[image: Sample Screenshot]